# ¿Cómo combinar el método asincrónico con un progressbar? [WPF, C#]

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, async

Muy buenas, quisiera saber ¿cómo hacer que la barra de progreso aumente dependiendo del tiempo de descarga de un archivo? Por ahora hice que la barra quede en un estado indeterminado pero quisiera hacerlo un poco mejor, la verdad es que no sé mucho sobre como usar la barra de progreso, vi tutoriales pero siento que no entiendo mucho, quisiera saber como sería en este caso, estaré agradecido si me ayudaran.

```
   pbStatus.IsIndeterminate = true;
                        
   await youtube.Videos.Streams.DownloadAsync(streamInfo, Combo_Ubication.Text + $@"\{video.Title}.mp3");
   pbStatus.IsIndeterminate = false;
```

Comment: El uso de backgroundworker precisamente ejecuta esos 3 métodos sin que tengas que escribir todo el código.Te permite actualizar el UI sin que se quede pegado, además podrías usar tus llamadas de forma async. [enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes descargar archivos con el siguiente método, el mismo te permite usar un evento que te ira avisando el progreso de descargar del mismo, y cuando el evento es llamado ese evento disparado debera actualizar tu UI.

```
string REMOTE_FILE_PATH = "https:\\......lo-que-sea.zip";
string LOCAL_FILE_PATH = Combo_Ubication.Text + $@"\{video.Title}.mp3";

private void DownloadNow()
{
    //using System.Net;
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri(REMOTE_FILE_PATH);
    client.DownloadProgressChanged +=client_DownloadProgressChanged;
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += client_DownloadFileCompleted;
    client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, LOCAL_FILE_PATH);
}

void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pbStatus.IsIndeterminate = false;
    pbStatus.Value = (double)e.ProgressPercentage;
    Console.WriteLine("TRANSFERIDO: " + (double)e.ProgressPercentage);
}

void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    pbStatus.IsIndeterminate = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Listo!");
    //using System.Diagnostics;
    Process.Start(LOCAL_FILE_PATH);  
}
```

Suerte!